# What's meaning of the "p" in the name datetime.datetime.strptime()?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm learning the python's datetime module, and found two useful functions:
`datetime.strptime()` and `datetime.strftime()`.

I know that the functions meaning, `datetime.strftime()` could convert a time object to a specified format string, I could understand the `strftime` as "string from time", the "f" means "from". But what's the meaning of the "p" in `strptime()`? I understand it's a function as "convert a string to a time object", so it should be `strttime()` instead of `strptime()`.

Who else also feel confused on this function name?
Thanks in advance no matter you could answer this question or share the same confusion with me.

Comment: The `p` stands for "parse". Practically, it **parses** the `string` into a `datetime` object.

Comment: The "f" in strftime actually comes from "format".

Comment: This question is really asked by others. And let me list the possible answers here: 1. Pointer(time object pointer), 2. Parser(String's parser to a time object), 3. Posix(return a posix time object), 4. Put( put a string represented time to a time object)

Answer (score 1):

These are the developer doc string says. I guess `p` stands for parsing `datetime` from a `string` type.

```
In [2]: datetime.datetime.strptime??
Docstring: string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [3]: datetime.datetime.strftime??
Docstring: format -> strftime() style string.
Type:      method_descriptor
```